# Need a simple publisher subscriber

Tags: python, django

We have inherited a tool which runs on Py 2.6.8 and Django 1.3.5. Our tool accepts change requests (CRs) via APIs and persists that into some tables.

A new requirement has come where we perform some validations and transform the data into another set of tables. We want this to happen, preferably, asynchronously. Thus, when a CR comes, in the save method of the models.Model classes we start a thread. That thread pushes the change details into a queue (which is also a table).

A cron job running every second polls the table and performs the necessary validation & data transformation.

This is our current (v0.1) implementation which we did fairly simply. And this is basically a publisher-subscriber scenario which happens async in the background.

I want to move away from the constant polling of the cron job to a publisher-subscriber method. What will help me (keeping in mind the old stack we have)?

Comment: btw, you need to change your questions title, it doesnot say anything about the question body

Comment: I had to get the v0.1 implementation out quickly and I did that. Now that I have time, I am open to improvements. I  can see that we are doing a publisher-subscriber. Hence, the title.

Comment: I dont see anything related to publisher-subcriber in your question! "how to make async calls in better way" would be more appropriate

Comment: Ok. Accepted. :-) I have made changes to the post.

Comment: nice! :)) I just wanted that people who has the same problem will also find your question

Answer (score 3):

you may consider celery and rabbitmq which is much better suitable for things like yours.

the idea is: in your app you create a file called `tasks.py` and there you put the data validation and transformation logic into a function, may be called `validate_and_transfer()`

```
# tasks.py
from celery import task

@task
def validate_and_transfer(data):
    # validated_data = validate(data)
    # res = transform(data)
    # if 'OK' in res.status:
    #     lalalalala
```

and in your model's save method, you just call the function and it does the job for you asyncly..

[Here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/index.html) is the documentation for Celery, you find there also how to set it up with django etc..

hope, this helps